# Retrofit no key name on URL parameter

Tags: android, json, api, rest, retrofit

I need to call an Api on retrofit just like that sample:

http://api.paco.com/c?***version_int***&***somekey***&***someotherkey***&***lastkey***&***user+input***&***some_base64***

I dont need the key parameter specification, just the value straight implicit  (ie: &somekey=value&someotherkey=value)

I'd concatenate on a @Path, but I have some doubts about the elegance.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, be more detailed.

Comment: http://api.paco.com/c/?{version}&{salt}&{time}&{hard}&{text}&{image}

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: DaniloDeQueiroz still having problems or shall I update my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way.

You can pass entire query to your rest api method like this:

```
callMethod("?version_int&somekey&someotherkey&lastkey&user+input&some_base64")
```

In REST api method use it like this:

```
@GET("/c{query}")
void callMethod(@EncodedPath("query") String query);
```

I hope it helps!