# Retrofit2 no key name on URL parameter

Tags: android, http, get, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit2

I need to ask api with simply get looking like that
http://1.1.1.1/get?key=value1&value2

How can I have query with only value? As value2 in above example?
I've tried like here:
[Retrofit no key name on URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353683/retrofit-no-key-name-on-url-parameter)

- Retrofit change ? sign to %3F.
- @Query("") will do something like this &=value2
- @QueryMap("") with empty value will od something like this &value2=

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this kind of case you can directly call entire URL.

```
@GET()
Call<ResponseVO> test(@Url() String url);
```

And call

```
test("http://1.1.1.1/get?key=value1&value2")
```

Answer (score 4):

With the latest version of Retrofit2 `@QueryName`

```
@GET("http://1.1.1.1/get")
Call<Object> getYourData(@Query("key") String key, @QueryName String value);
```

When you call the method, each query name is appended to the URL. You can see the JavaDoc here: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/QueryName.html

Answer (score 1):

Please encode query parameter value value1&value2 to value1%26value2 like

```
http://1.1.1.1/get?key=value1&value2
```

to

```
http://1.1.1.1/get?key=value1%26value2
```

when you passing in

```
@GET("http://1.1.1.1/get?")
Call<Object> getYourData(@Query("key") String value);
```

Comment: don't work don't chang %26 to &
regardless encoding or not
Moreover without encoding it will change % to %25, so we will have %2526 :)

Answer (score -1):

```
@GET("http://1.1.1.1/get?key=value")
Call<Object> getYourData(@Query("value") String value);
```

And then when you call "getYourData" just put your value1 and value2 in separate strings and concatenate them and pass that new string to "getYourData" method.

P.S dont forget this sign "&" when merging two strings together.

Comment: don't work - & is changed to %26 
regardless encoding or not

Comment: did you make this api?

Comment: I'm guessing that you did so the proper way would be to do something like this: http://1.1.1.1/get/?key1=value1 & key2=value2